# Volume and center of mass of a drilled out hemisphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Through a homogeneous hemisphere with radius $R$ a hole is drilled with radius $R_0=R/2$ centrally so that the hole axis coincides with the hemisphere's axis of 
symmetry.

(a) How much is the remaining volume of the hemisphere after the  hole has been drilled out?

(b) How much has the hemisphere mass center moved and towards which direction due to drilling?

I don't know how to set up the integral or generally how to solve this problem.

Comment: Think at the whole as a cilinder with the sphere surface as a bound and calculate the integral difference

Comment: You studied integral of volume bounded by surface? (I'm sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Take a cilinder that fit in the whole and bound it with your halfsphere. The volume of the half sphere minus the volune of the volume of the bounded cilinder is what are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Due to symmetry it can be integrated as a single variable. Calculate and remove volumes of cap and cylinder from that of hemisphere.

It so happens remaining volume can be expressed in terms of the height of the remaining cylinder *only*.